# how to execute a link in ajax called php script

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, curl

i am trying to execute a link so that page do not redirect but just execute the link..

i tried with the below curl pgm (completely new to curl)

```
  $ch = curl_init(); // Initializing
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://api.smsgatewayhub.com/smsapi/pushsms.aspx?user=stthomasmtc&pwd=429944&to=9176411081&sid=STMTSC&msg=Dear Sam,%20choir%20practice%20will%20be%20held%20in%20our%20Church%20on%20July%2031%20at%208:00%20pm.%20Thanks,%20St.%20Thomas%20MTC!&fl=0&gwid=2"); // Set URI
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); //Set Header
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 300); // Time-out in seconds
$result = curl_exec($ch); // Executing
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if ($httpCode != 200) {
$result = ""; // Executing
}
curl_close($ch); // Closing the channel
return $result;
```

but this didnt work as expected... i tried to use javascript code in php echoed, but since that php file was called via ajax that script didnt get execute.. :(

calling pgm

```
  <div class="button_div">
                     <input type="button" onclick="send_sms()" value="Send SMS" class="submit">  
            </div>
```

and the javascript functions

```
    function send_sms()
        {
            var sms_msg=(document.getElementById('preview_box').value).trim();
    /*        var prayer_group_nm=(document.getElementById('prayer_group').value).trim();
            if ((recepient==='prayer_grp')&&(prayer_group_nm==='select'))
            {
                alert('Select the appropriate Prayer group');
                return;
            }
            */

            if (sms_msg==='')
            {
                alert ('Preview MSG prior to sending!');
            }
            else
            {

                myurl = '../sp/send_sms_sp.php';
                parms="?recepient="+recepient+"&sms_msg="+sms_msg;
                modurl = myurl+parms;  
                if (recepient==='prayer_grp')
                {
                    modurl=modurl+"&prayer_group_nm="+prayer_group_nm;
                }

                response='sms_templates_response';  //setting div where response is being displayed
                swtch='send_sms_state';

                ajax_call.call();

                //removing earlier checked state of radio buttons
                $("input:radio").attr("checked", false);
                document.getElementById('preview_box').value='';

                //hiding out unwanted divs
                $(".button_div").hide();
                $("#preview").hide();

            }

        }
```

and ajax_call() function...

```
        function ajax_call()            
        {
          var xmlhttp;    
          {
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
              {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
              xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
              }
            else
              {// code for IE6, IE5
              xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
              }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
              {
              if (xmlhttp.readyState===4 && xmlhttp.status===200)
                {
                    if (swtch!=='preview')
                    {
                        document.getElementById(response).innerHTML=(xmlhttp.responseText);    
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        raw_template=xmlhttp.responseText; 
                                                    //do not move the below code to the calling function - as it has a bug.. will not work as expected, if done
                        modified_msg='';
                        get_modified_msg.call();
                        document.getElementById(response).value='Dear (name), '+modified_msg.trim()+'. Thanks, St. Thomas MTC!';
                    }
                   // return;
                }
                else 
                {
                    if (swtch!=='preview')
                    {
                        document.getElementById(response).innerHTML ='<img src="../animation/ajax-loader.gif">';
                    }

                }
              }
                xmlhttp.open("GET", modurl, true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }  // return;
    };
```

and the called php

```
 <?php
//retreiving data from db and then below code
        $sender_id='STMTSC';
            $pwd='429999';
            $url='http://api.smsgatewayhub.com/smsapi/pushsms.aspx?user=stthomasmtc&pwd='.$pwd.'&to='.$mob.'&sid='.$sender_id.'&msg='.$msg.'&fl=0&gwid=2';

            echo $url.'<br>';

            echo '<script src="../jquery/jquery-1.10.1.js">';
            echo '</script>';

            echo '        <script>';
           // echo '            $(document).ready(function(){';


            echo '            $.ajax({';
            echo '            type: "POST",';
                 //       url: "http://api.smsgatewayhub.com/smsapi/pushsms.aspx?user=stthomasmtc&pwd=429944&to=9176411081&sid=STMTSC&msg=Dear Sam,%20choir%20practice%20will%20be%20held%20in%20our%20Church%20on%20July%2031%20at%208:00%20pm.%20Thanks,%20St.%20Thomas%20MTC!&fl=0&gwid=2",
            echo '            url: "'.$url.'" ,';
            echo '            data: { message: "hello" }';
            echo '            })';
            echo '            .done(function( msg ) {';
            echo '            alert( "script executed successfully ");';
            echo '            this.preventDefault();'; // stops navigating from the page while <a> click or on submit click.
            echo '            }); ';
            //echo '        });';
            echo 'window.alert("ending script")';
            echo '         </script>';

//update of db as log
```

userid and pwd are invalid in this scenario;
since its script within php which is called via ajax, things aren't working :(
can you please provide me a way to execute a link in php page tat's called via ajax;

thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: How are you calling `send_sms()`?

Comment: What do you mean by "execute a link"? You mean call a Javascript function when you click on the link? Use `href="javascript:send_sms()"`

Comment: You should put `encodeURIComponent` around all the AJAX parameters. Otherwise you'll have problems if they contain spaces or other special characters.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for your response.. yes, i call send_sms() with button click - onclick event... when i try to directly execute the php script, the javascript within it works; but when i try to call it via ajax, it doesn't work.. (my entire work is stalled as i couldnt find a way out:() can you let me know the corrections i need to do... when i googled, it says am supposed to use eval() function.. but am not sure how to use it..

Comment: Add the code that calls `send_sms` to your question.

Comment: It looks OK at first glance, are there any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: dont find any... since this javascript tat is not executed is within the php, (which is called via ajax), we do not find it listed in firebug either :( 
do you hav anyother way in which i could execute a link...

Comment: You mean the JS is in the page that you're downloading with CURL? CURL just downloads the page, it's not a browser so it doesn't execute JS.

Comment: i just tried two routes.. one with curl and another with javascript... to execute a link without page being redirected.. 
curl didnt work... in javascript since its called within php by ajax, it doesnt get executed either :(

i just need to execute a link in php...

Comment: Yuo're losing me, sorry.

Comment: you need to bookmark the php manual and the jquery and javascript manuals. its fairly obvious that you have no idea what you are doing, but you can benefit immensely from studying the manuals of each language, and eventually bringing your code up to par.

Comment: @r3wt: He doesn't even use jquery... maybe that's the point he should start with.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois in the topmost javascript example, he is using jQuery in a few places, which is confusing. its obvious a copy and paste job with little understanding.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you're trying to do, but let me tell you this: cURL is a tool which can open a website and return the ouput. It can't do anything else like executing javascript. Also is forbidden for Javascript to call urls with not the same url as the website they're currently on. So you can't make an AJAX request to `api.smsgatewayhub.com` unless your website is api.smsgatewayhub.com. I don't know what you exactly mean with 'execute a link'.

Take a look at the sample PHP SMS API given by smsgatewayhub.com.

http://www.smsgatewayhub.com/sms-gateway-api/php-sms-script

Comment: i did check on this doc first.. but am not sure which code to be replaced for our need... would be grateful if you can guide me on the same (i checked with the customer support team and they declined to respond) thanks a lot!

Comment: Well, I don't really know the script. For the start maybe you should clean the sample code a bit (like indent, make more whitespaces). Maybe then you're able to read the code. A php developer should be able to read the php code of strangers, if not, because too less whitespaces or not indented, then do the things necessary to make it more readable. I'd have to do that too.